# ServiceStack GitHub Code Branches confusing & lot of repetitive folders everywhere

Tags: servicestack

So I'm looking at the list of projects here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack

I see all the individual projects for download (e.g. ServiceStack.Text, etc.)

But then there's a main "ServiceStack" download and I noticed it contains in it's src folder a ton of ServiceStack projects including the base projects such as Common but leaves some out (like it doesn't have ServiceStack.Text).  Furthermore, the projects in src are using names like SL4, SL5 which is prob the versions?  This is totally misleading and confusing.

So I created my own solution, downloaded individual projects and added them to my solution.  Ok, do I do that or do I use the main ServiceStack download..I mean I see repeat of things all over such as again there is an src\ServiceStack.Common in the ServiceStack download and so on.

How the heck are we supposed to be including this stuff...via individual projects or just use that [one huge ServiceStack folder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) on this download page?

Comment: Maybe use nuget to sort out the project references. Latest service stack version includes symbol files in nuget package so you can step through the source if required.

Comment: so I do need the source.  We are not relying just on the binaries.  So if I nuget it down that's only gonna bring down binaries right?  that's not what we want, we want to be actively referencing the core code inside our solution and if we ever have to modify the StackService code we can do so.  Otherwise there is no point for us to use this API if we can't also modify the source code.